# SQL to delete product attributes

Tags: attributes

I installed a module that added some product attributes but did not remove them on uninstall. Their existence is throwing errors. I expected a "delete attribute" button to be there when I click into the attribute, but the button is missing. What is the SQL to delete product attributes? THANKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way which I generally follow for these type of tasks is : 
First create a test.php in magento root directory 
Place below code there

```
    <?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

    require_once './app/Mage.php';
    umask(0);
    Mage::app();

    $attr = 'test_remove'; //attribute code to remove

    $setup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'core_setup');
    try {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $setup->removeAttribute('catalog_product', $attr);
        $setup->endSetup();
        echo $attr . " attribute is removed";
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        print_r($e->getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In a bootstrapped Magento environment, you can just do

```
$setup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
$setup->startSetup();
$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_product','attribute_code');
$setup->endSetup();
```